# Attunity driver fails when run from sql server agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, attunity

This is unique. My package runs perfectly in Visual Studio debug mode, but when I put it to run via sql server agent, I get the following error:

> 'Oracle source cannot run on installed edition of Integration
>   Services. It requires Enterprise Edition(64 bit) or higher'

[image: img]

Configuration:

- SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition
- Attunity driver 4.0 and 5.0

[Attunity page clearly states that it is compatible with developer edition(under system requirements)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950)

Am I missing some property or permission in Agent services?